# ajax GET works on localhost but not online

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

When I run the application at localhost it works fine, but when I run online i get "404 Page not found". The same code is online and local.

There is the ajax code:

```
var FormAll = $("#formPdf");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "/Objetivo/SendPdf",
    data: FormAll.serialize(),
    success: function (resultado) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

There is the Python code:

```
@app.route('/Objetivo/SendPdf',methods=['GET'])
def sendPdf():
    try:
       ##Do Something
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the ajax when the url:` /Objetivo/SendPdf` show 404 Error. It's probably because the route doesn't exist on your server. Please check if your server is correctly built and if you've specified correct CORS headers in your server-side script.

Comment: the route exists

Comment: if it exists it wouldn't throw 404 error. Here you have the http error code list: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I know that, that is why I am asking. Why it is happening

Comment: This is `flask` right? Is your flask program able to serve up other content? I think flask, by default, runs in debug mode and refuses external connections. Are you specifiying "--host=0.0.0.0" when you run your flask to make the server publicly available.

Comment: I think maybe the web sever is receiving a lot of requests, that's why it is happening. It is not the best of the servers...

Comment: and yes, it's Flask

Answer (score 0):

From the flask [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/):

> **Externally Visible Server**
>   If you run the server you will notice that
>   the server is only accessible from your own computer, not from any
>   other in the network. This is the default because in debugging mode a
>   user of the application can execute arbitrary Python code on your
>   computer.
>
> If you have the debugger disabled or trust the users on your network,
>   you can make the server publicly available simply by adding
>   --host=0.0.0.0 to the command line:
>
> flask run --host=0.0.0.0 This tells your operating system to listen on
>   all public IPs.